# Actualizar datos en ASP .NET MVC - Relación muchos a muchos

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

### Hola buenos días a todos.

Soy nuevo en .NET y estoy realizando una pequeña práctica **MVC** que tiene dos simples tablas. Esas tablas son **Users** y **SocialNetwork**. Un usuario tiene una serie de redes sociales y una red social es usada por varios usuarios (many to many).

**El problema que tengo es en el campo muchos a muchos de User**, **el cual no me actualiza**. He mirado mil tutoriales y post y ninguno coinciden en como tengo todo configurado, ya que hay muchas formas de hacer lo mismo y muchas versiones antiguas. Me costó llegar hasta el punto que estoy y todas las propuestas que encuentro requieren cambiar por completo el programa.

**La clase User:**

```
public class User{

    public User(){
        ManyNetworks = new HashSet<SocialNetwork>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Apellidos")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    //Red social favorita
    [Display(Name = "Red Favorita")]
    public int Network_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SocialNetwork FavouriteNetwork { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Redes Sociales")]
    public virtual ICollection<SocialNetwork> ManyNetworks { get; set; }
}
```

Para las redes sociales tengo una clase con otra colección, y **Entity Framework** se ocupa de generarla tabla intermedia en el **first code**. Aún así, **en la clase contexto tengo la siguiente configuración:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){

        // configures many-to-many relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<SocialNetwork>(s => s.ManyNetworks)
            .WithMany(c => c.ManyUsers)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                cs.MapRightKey("NetworkId");
                cs.ToTable("UsersNetwork");
            });
    }
```

Las restricciones indican borrado en cascada para usuario. **Mi archivo de migración se configuró así.**

```
CreateTable("dbo.Users",c => new {
                    User_Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false),
                    Surname = c.String(),
                    Network_Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.User_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SocialNetworks", t => t.Network_Id,
             cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.Network_Id);

CreateTable("dbo.UsersNetwork",c => new{
                    UserId = c.Int(nullable: true),
                    NetworkId = c.Int(nullable: true),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.NetworkId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: false)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.SocialNetworks", t => t.NetworkId, 
             cascadeDelete: false)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.NetworkId);
```

Finalmente, muestro la acción [HttpPost] donde edito el objeto. Utilizo la misma metodología para enviar y recibir los datos que en otros métodos que funcionan, **debugeando**, veo que crea bien el objeto pero no se guarda correctamente **ya que la tabla intermedia sigue igual.** He probado a borrar sus relaciones intermedias pero sigue sin añadir las nuevas. El fallo debe estar en Entry.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 
    "User_Id,Name,Surname,Network_Id,ManyNetworks")] 
    User user, FormCollection Cs){

        int[] SelectedNetworks = Array
        .ConvertAll(Cs[4].Split(','),int.Parse);
        user.ManyNetworks.Clear();//Borrar para probar

        //db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        //    "DELETE FROM UsersNetwork WHERE UserId = @id", new SqlParameter("id", user.User_Id));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (int i in SelectedNetworks)
            {
                user.ManyNetworks.Add(db.SocialNetworks.Find(i));
            }
            //user.ManyNetworks = selected;//Sustituimos la nueva lista
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges(); //Aquí no guarda
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Network_Id = new SelectList(
            db.SocialNetworks.OrderBy(c => c.NetworkName), 
            "Network_Id", 
            "NetworkName", 
            user.Network_Id);
        ViewBag.Networks = new MultiSelectList(
            db.SocialNetworks.OrderBy(c => c.NetworkName), 
            "Network_Id", 
            "NetworkName", 
            user.ManyNetworks.Select(s => s.Network_Id));
        return View(user);
    }
```

**Les agradecería la ayuda. Muchas gracias de antemano.**

Answer (score 2):

Me solucioné el problema yo mismo y publico aquí una respuesta para cerrar el hilo y que ayude al que le pase lo mismo. El problema cuando tenemos propiedades añadidas a un modelo, las cuales no ha mapeado `EntityFramework`, es que al mover los datos a través de `[Bind()]` solo reconoce las que tiene mapeadas. Hay formas largas y tediosas para solucionar eso, pero una más fácil es el `FormCollection` La forma **Errónea** que intentaba hacer es la siguiente:

**No funciona**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = 
  "User_Id,Name,Surname,Network_Id,ManyNetworks")] 
  User user, FormCollection Cs){

    int[] SelectedNetworks = Array
    .ConvertAll(Cs[4].Split(','),int.Parse);
    user.ManyNetworks.Clear();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (int i in SelectedNetworks)
        {
            user.ManyNetworks.Add(db.SocialNetworks.Find(i));
        }

        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges(); //Aquí no guarda
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.Network_Id = new SelectList(
        db.SocialNetworks.OrderBy(c => c.NetworkName), 
        "Network_Id", 
        "NetworkName", 
        user.Network_Id);
    ViewBag.Networks = new MultiSelectList(
        db.SocialNetworks.OrderBy(c => c.NetworkName), 
        "Network_Id", 
        "NetworkName", 
        user.ManyNetworks.Select(s => s.Network_Id));
    return View(user);
}
```

Entonces lo que hacems es eliminar del parámetro el objeto `User`y dejamos solamente el del `FormCollection`. El `FormCollection`es una colección que contiene todos los parámetros editados en el formulario y que se rellena al ejecutarse el `submit`. Hay que tener en cuenta que los índices de la colección cambian dependiendo de si se ha añadido o no un valor a una propiedad, es decir, si uno de los atributos de relación foránea se queda a null, `FormCollection`será más pequeño y los índices podrían no coincidir.

La manera como la gestioné es la siguiente:

**Funciona**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection Fc)
{
    //Buscar el usuario a modificar
    var userUpdate = db.Users.Find(int.Parse(Fc[1]));
    //Redes seleccionadas
    int[] SelectedNetworks = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (db.SocialNetworks.Any()) //Solo si hay redes disponibles
        {

            userUpdate.NetworkId = int.Parse(Fc[4]);
            //Recogemos redes seleccionadas en array, este campo tiene los 
            //indices en un string separados por comas "1,2,3,4"
            SelectedNetworks = Array.ConvertAll(Fc[5].Split(','), int.Parse);
            userUpdate.ManyNetworks.Clear();//Limpiamos valores antiguos

            //Actualizar las redes
            foreach (var i in SelectedNetworks)
            {
                userUpdate.ManyNetworks.Add(db.SocialNetworks.Find(i));
            }
        }

        //Actualizar resto de datos
        userUpdate.Name = Fc[2];
        userUpdate.Surname = Fc[3];

        //Guardar
        db.Entry(userUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    if (db.SocialNetworks.Any())//Solo si hay redes disponibles(evitar null)
    {
        ViewBag.NetworkId = new SelectList(
        db.SocialNetworks.OrderBy(s => s.NetworkName),
        "NetworkId",
        "NetworkName");
        ViewBag.MultiNetworks = new MultiSelectList(
            db.SocialNetworks.OrderBy(s => s.NetworkName),
            "NetworkId",
            "NetworkName");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.NetworkId = null;
        ViewBag.MultiNetworks = null;
    }

    return View(userUpdate);
}
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien, y si hay alguien que tiene mejores formas de hacerlo, estoy dispuesto a aprender.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y perdona por la ausencia prolongada